# TypeScript paths don't work with index

Tags: typescript

I want to use typescript paths feature, but it does not work with index. For example:

```
 "paths": {
    "company/utils/*": ["./src/somepath/utils/*"],
 }
```

In the utils folder, I have an index file which exports all the files.

```
// index.ts


export * from './a';
export * from './b';
```

What I want it to be able to write the imports like this:

```
import {A, B} from 'company/utils';
```

But it does not work, I need to explicitly specify the index.

```
import {A, B} from 'company/utils/index';
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you know it does not work? What is the error since this works fine for me.

Comment: It works like that: import {A, B} from 'company/utils'; ?

Comment: I get Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'company/utils' in '......./src/somepath/utils'

Comment: Please post your `tsconfig.json`